# writing unit test for many to many model in django program

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, model, django-testing

in my django projects, I have a two class like following:

```
class DataTag(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
relations = models.ManyToManyField('DataTag',
related_name='related_data_tags', blank=True)
```

and the another class is:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('DataTag',related_name = 'data')
    def tag_name(self):
        if self.tags.all():
            return self.tags.all()[0].title
        return ''
```

both my models work, but now I want to write a test for main_tag_name, and checking if this function returns a true value or not.until now I write the following:

```
from unittest import TestCase
class DataTest(TestCase):
    def test_tag_name(self):
        self.data = Data.objects.create()
        self.tag1 = DataTag.objects.create()
```

I am new on writing test. please help me for writing this test.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

Create a Data object:
`data_object = Data.objects.create()`

Now, create a tag for this:
`data_object.tags.create(name='Foo')`

You can assert that the relationship exists: `self.assertTrue(data_objects.tags.exists())`

And now you can assert that `tag_name` returns what you expect: `self.assertEqual(data_object.tag_name, 'Foo')`